# How to properly use git with blender?

Tags: animation, texturing, objects, shaders, blend-files

We normally save backups with .blend1 and so on (but I will ignore all the .blendNumber files), but if I wanted to have a repository and maybe 2 or more people working on it at the time, how should I go about that (is possible to resolve conflicts?).

Also what about the textures because if I pack them and only change the texture, all the blend file will be changed so it can conflict if some one changes the texture and other person change the model.

Or I should go in the path of one repo per asset?

I should also say that this is on the path of game develop, but it should be helpful for movies, short cuts and any other that want to use git as a history as on:

- http://who-t.blogspot.mx/2009/12/on-commit-messages.html
- http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/
- https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Writing-good-commit-messages

From Neil answer

https://github.com/ldo/blendgit

Comment: have a look at this - https://github.com/ldo/blendgit

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest checking out [ShapeDo](http://shapedo.com/), which is like github for 3D cad files.

It suppoorts blender files and tracks changes much better since it "understands" 3D files and doesn't just compare the raw text or binary file content. Also supports previews for collaborations, and is still free as far as I know.

Comment: No longer free, it seems. Any other alternatives?

Comment: @TLousky do you still have a copy?